# JSON to BSON conversion, mongodb c

Tags: c, json, mongodb, bson

I have a moderately complex JSON object, stored as a `char *`, that I would like to convert to BSON to input it into mongodb using the c "driver" (http://api.mongodb.org/c/0.4/bson.html). While I can use a JSON parser like cJSON to split the object into its elements and add them individualy using commands like `bson_append_int( b, "count", 1001 );`. I believe the conversion could and should be simpler than that (as there is no loss or gain to the conversion), does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

I think I am looking for something similar to the cpp `BSONObj mongo::fromjson (   const string &  str  )` but I cant find the relavant c function in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not that familiar with the C driver but perhaps these two functions might help:

[bson_init_from_json](https://github.com/mongodb/libbson/blob/master/doc/bson_init_from_json.rst)
[bson_new_from_json](https://github.com/mongodb/libbson/blob/master/doc/bson_new_from_json.rst)

**Converting JSON to BSON**

```
bson_t *b;
bson_error_t error;

b = bson_new_from_json ("{\"a\":1}", -1, &error);

if (!b) {
   printf ("Error: %s\n", error.message);
} else {
   bson_destroy (b);
}
```

http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/json.html

Comment: the links are dead, and SO users are encouraged to copy a snipped of the answer instead of just links :)